# Suggested edit that classifies for the Radical Reject option, but is also pretty good

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I just came across [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/117115).

It does qualify for a reject as "Radical edit" in my opinion:

> This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.

The edit does indeed completely change the question.

**But**, it's also transforms a should-have-been-posted-on-meta-and-probably-closed-as-dup question into a pretty good<sup>1</sup> version of the original author's question...

What should one do when confronted with such a situation?

<sup>1</sup><sub>I know nothing about R, so I don't really know, and will not vote either way in this specific instance.</sub>

Comment: Side note: the original question [has just been re-posted here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108639/whats-wrong-with-this).

Comment: It might also noted, that the question has been reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was me. I rejected because:

- The question was already closed as off-topic and belonged on Meta (hence Radical change).
- A Quote from the question: `...but the filter of quality of stackoverflow is blocking this formulation`.
- Additionally, without knowing much about [r](/questions/tagged/r), I think `How to create a (3D) Histogram` is a well covered topic in that area and not exactly a good question.

Though, I might be wrong here, but I didn't find the question rescue worthy.

**Edit:** After some divine intervention the question has been reopened after the suggested edit in question was applied.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm actually wondering what would the Right Thing to do be **if** the resurrected question is, in fact, good. (Maybe that's too rare an event to think much about though.)

Comment: The thing is, if the question would have been good in the first place, we wouldn't have this discussion. ;) I think this is a very rare bordercase. But if this happens with a question which is worthy to rescue, I totally agree that we should rescue that one.

Comment: Right (: There might be corner cases with people uncomfortable with English, where a native speaker of their language could do a great fix up (or something like that). But accepting the edit in that case indeed makes perfect sense. With a vote to re-open to boot (if necessary).

Comment: Normally, I like @Jin's edits, I don't see anything wrong with the edit per se, if it wasn't for the history of the whole thing.