# Why can't I submit this question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

I am trying to submit this question, but the quality filter of Stack Overflow is blocking this formulation. Where is the error?

> i would like to create a 3d histogram with R,how can i do this with R?
>   example:
>   i have two variables and i want count how many times they falls in a
>   defined two dimensional bin. So i have the two varibles in the x and y axis,
>   while the z axis is the counting of the two variables.

*Edit:* Link to the original question: [Creating a 3D histogram with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684294/creating-a-3d-histogram-with-r)

Comment: Try capitalizing your i's for a start.

Comment: Maybe it's your spelling? "varibles"

Comment: Maybe you could share your question's title with us as well?

Comment: the title is present in the link.

Answer (score 3):

After you reposted the question it got closed again because five different people (including myself) considered it to not be a good question, it was considered off topic.

Before you ask your next question, have a little look around at some of the similar questions here on Meta, and check out this previous question: [Tips for getting really good answers on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81635/tips-for-getting-really-good-answers-on-so)

Comment: thank you, but i have read Tips for getting really....
but i don't understand where is different from my other previous questions. Seems to me that this question respects all the points of standard quality of stackoverflow.com. really i don't understand.

Comment: @emanuele, read and re-read Matt's comment on your question, for a start.

Comment: @Benjol i have read and re-read the Matt's comment. I have tried and re-tried but still not works.

Comment: @emanuele, if you've read and re-read, then what part of *"Try capitalizing your i's for a start"* didn't you understand?

Comment: @Benjol mr smarty pants what's your problem?